# Trading algorithm - actions in Q-learning/DQN

Tags: reinforcement-learning, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, q-learning

The following has completed using MATLAB.

I am trying to build a trading algorithm using Deep Q learning. I have just taken a years worth of daily stock prices and am using that as the training set.

My state space is my **`[money, stock, price]`**
`money` is the amount of cash I have,
`stock` is the number of stocks I have, and
`price` is the price of the stock at that time step.

The issue I am having is with the actions; looking online, people only have three actions, `{ buy | sell | hold }`.

My reward function is the difference between the value of portfolio value in the current time step and the previous time step.

But using just three actions, I am unsure how to choose to buy, lets say 67 stocks at the price?

I am using a neural network to approximate the q-values. It has three inputs
`[money, stock, price]` and 202 outputs, i.e. I can sell between 0 and 100 number of stock, 0, I can hold the stock, or I can buy 1-100 stock.

Can anyone shed some light on the how can I reduce this to 3 actions?

My code is  :

```
%  p is the stock price
% sp is the stock price at the next time interval 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

hidden_layers =   1;
actions       = 202;
net           = newff( [-1000000 1000000;-1000000 1000000;0 1000;],
                       [hidden_layers, actions],
                       {'tansig','purelin'},
                       'trainlm'
                       );

net           = init( net );

net.trainParam.showWindow = false;

% neural network training parameters -----------------------------------
net.trainParam.lr     =   0.01;
net.trainParam.mc     =   0.1;
net.trainParam.epochs = 100;

% parameters for q learning --------------------------------------------
epsilon        =    0.8;
gamma          =    0.95;
max_episodes   = 1000;
max_iterations = length( p ) - 1;

reset          =    false;
inital_money   = 1000;
inital_stock   =    0;

%These will be where I save the outputs
save_s        = zeros( max_iterations, max_episodes );
save_pt       = zeros( max_iterations, max_episodes );
save_Q_target = zeros( max_iterations, max_episodes );
save_a        = zeros( max_iterations, max_episodes );

% construct the inital state -------------------------------------------
% a           = randi( [1 3], 1, 1 );  
s             = [inital_money;inital_stock;p( 1, 1 )];


% construct initial q matrix -------------------------------------------
Qs            = zeros( 1, actions );
Qs_prime      = zeros( 1, actions );


for     i = 1:max_episodes
    for j = 1:max_iterations             % max_iterations --------------

        Qs = net( s );

        %% here we will choose an action based on epsilon-greedy strategy

        if ( rand() <= epsilon )
            [Qs_value  a] = max(Qs);
        else 
            a = randi( [1 202], 1, 1 );
        end

        a2                 = a - 101;
        save_a(j,i)        = a2;
        sp                 = p( j+1, 1 ) ; 
        pt                 = s( 1 ) + s( 2 ) * p( j, 1 );
        save_pt(j,i)       = pt; 
        [s_prime,reward]   = simulateStock( s, a2, pt, sp );

        Qs_prime           = net( s_prime );

        Q_target           = reward + gamma * max( Qs_prime );
        save_Q_target(j,i) = Q_target;
        Targets            = Qs;

        Targets( a )       =  Q_target;

        save_s( j, i )     = s( 1 );
        s                  = s_prime;
    end

    epsilon = epsilon * 0.99 ; 
    reset   = false; 
    s       = [inital_money;inital_stock;p(1,1)];
end

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
function[s_prime,reward] = simulateStock( s, a, pt, sp )
                           money   = s(1);
                           stock   = s(2);
                           price   = s(3);

                           money   = money - a * price ;
                           money   = max( money, 0 );
                           stock   = s(2) + a;
                           stock   = max( stock, 0 );

                           s_prime = [money;stock;sp];
                           reward  = ( money + stock * price ) - pt;
end
```

Comment: This question seems too broad to me. Avoid asking multiple questions at once. I'm unsure if someone will be able to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks, I have just started. I am doing a project in my own time. Everything is fair.

Comment: thanks m7913d , I am more interested in the actions part than the convergence.

Answer (score 3):

### Actions: ill-defined
 <sup>( if not giving an ultimate reason for so flattened, decaffeinated & knowingly short-cut model )</sup>

You may be right, that using a range of just **`{ buy | hold | sell }`** actions is a frequent habit for academic papers, where authors sometimes decide to illustrate their demonstrated academic efforts on improving learning / statistical methods and opt to pick an exemplary application in a trading domain. The pity is, this could be done in academic papers, but not in the reality of trading.

### Why?

Even with an elementary view on trading, the problem is much more complex. As a brief reference, there are **more than five principal domains** of such model-space. Given a trading is to be modelled, one cannot remain without a fully described strategy --

```
Tru-Strategy := {    SelectPOLICY,
                     DetectPOLICY,
                        ActPOLICY,
                   AllocatePOLICY,
                  TerminatePOLICY
                  }
```

Any whatever motivated simplification, that would opt to omit any single one domain of these five principal domains will become whatever but a truly Trading Strategy.

One can easily figure out, what comes out of just training ( the worse from later harnessing such model in doing real trades with ) an ill-defined model, that is not coherent with the reality.

Sure, it can reach ( and will ( again, unless ill-formulated minimiser's criterion function ) ) some mathematical function's minimum, but that does not ensure the reality to immediately change it's so far natural behaviours and to **start "obey" the ill-defined model** and to "dance" according to such oversimplified or otherwise skewed ( ill-modelled )-opinions about the reality.

---

### Rewards: ill-defined
 <sup>( if not giving a reason for ignoring the fact or delayed rewards )</sup>

If in doubts what this means, try to follow an example:
Today, the Strategy-Model decides to **`A:Buy(AAPL,67)`**.
Tomorrow, `AAPL` goes down, some 0.1% and thus the immediate reward ( as was proposed above ) is negative, thus punishing such decision. The Model is stimulated not to do it ( do not buy AAPL ).

The point is, that after some period of time, AAPL rises much higher, producing much higher reward compared to initial fluctuations in D2D `Close`, which is known, but the proposed Strategy-Model Q-fun simply principally erroneously did not reflect at all.

### Beware WYTIWYG -- What You Train Is What You Get ...

This means an as-is-Model could be trained to act according to the such defined stimuli, but it's actual behaviour will favour NOTHING but such extremely naive intraday *"quasi-scalping"* shots with limited ( if any at all ) support from actual Market State & Market Dynamics as are available by many industry-wide accepted quantitative models.

**So,** sure, **one can train a reality-blind model, that was kept blind & deaf** ( ignoring the reality of the Problem Domain ), **but for what sake?**

---

**Epilogue:**

There is nothing like a "*Data Science*"
<sub>even when MarCom & HR beat their drums & whistles, as they indeed do a lot nowadays</sub>

---

Why?

Exactly because the above observed rationale. Having data-points is nothing. Sure, it is better than standing clueless in front of the customer without a single observation of the reality, but the Data-points do not save the game.

It is the domain-knowledge, that starts to make some sense from the Data-points, not the Data-points *per se*.

If still in doubts, if one has a few terabytes of numbers, there is no *Data Science* to tell you, what the data-points represent.

On the other hand, if one knows, from the domain-specific context, these data-points ought be temperature readings, there is still no ***Data-Science*** God to tell you, whether there are all ( just by coincidence ) in [°K] or [°C]  ( if there are just positive readings >= 0.00001 ).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I understand your statements about academia papers, but the truth is that is what I am currently trying to replicate. This chap has published a post that I am trying to replicate.http://hallvardnydal.github.io/2016/03/12/deep_q/                                       Just a basic buy, sell ,hold scenario.  I think the issue might be with my simulateStock function, but when I run it, the systems seems to converge to some Q-value, as well as giving me a set of positive returns. I am training it on one year of data and testing it on three.

Comment: Enjoy your time. I respect a decision to spend time to experimentally prove if a smoke, blown into water will not create a pure gold, but I thought it might be helpfull to share the piece of an already available experience, that it will not. You've got my [+1] for your interest in doing science.

Comment: Could you provide some insight on how to just use three actions? As mentioned, i am unsure how they have set up the problem just to use three actions, how they would pick the number of stocks to buy/sell from just three actions.  Appreciate the [+1].

Comment: Hi @user3666197, thanks for the detailed answer. Could you please add a brief explanation about the five domains? E.g., what is the difference between Select and Detect?